# Need help with notation: What is the "$L^2+L^{\frac{4}{3}}$-Norm" supposed to be?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I recently came across the following notation in a paper. The author first estimated \begin{equation} \vert u (1-\vert u \vert^2)\vert \leq 2 \left[ \left\vert 1-\vert u \vert^2 \right\vert 1_{\lbrace \vert u \vert \leq 2\rbrace} +  \left( \vert u \vert^2-1 \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} 1_{\lbrace \vert u \vert \geq 2 \rbrace} \right]   \end{equation} which is correct.

Then he goes on to say

\begin{equation} \Vert u(1-\vert u \vert^2) \Vert_{L^2+L^{\frac{4}{3}}} \leq 2 \left[ \Vert 1 - \vert u \vert^2 \Vert_{L^2}+ \Vert 1 - \vert u \vert^2 \Vert_{L^2}^{\frac{3}{2}} \right] \end{equation}

My question is:

> What is the "$L^2+L^{\frac{4}{3}}$-Norm" supposed to be in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual definition of such a norm would be
$$
\Vert u \Vert_{L^2+L^{\frac{4}{3}}} =\inf\{\|u_1\|_{L^2}+\|u_2\|_{L^{4/3}}:u=u_1+u_2,u_1\in L^2,u_2\in L^{4/3}\}.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That also enables me to do the second estimate in my post.